# How do I push notification the data I get from the api?

Tags: android, mvvm, push-notification, android-workmanager

I'm pulling data from api using viewmodel and I want to push notification every hour, how can I do that?

Comment: Did you try something? Why it didn't work for you? You added `workmanager` tag - workmanager is indeed one way to solve this, so I assume you read its documentation and tried to solve your problem with workmanager - what was the problem?

Comment: workmanager sometimes works sometimes not works I set it to 15 minutes [link](https://gist.github.com/yusuftalhaklc/45e382594086799ffb9bcdf307695576) of my code